# Firebird 3 sysdba password stunning issue

Tags: wildfly, firebird, jaybird, firebird-3.0

I migrated from firebird 2.5.x to 3.0
i have changed firebird.conf :

```
WireCrypt = Enabled
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
```

after that here you are what happened:

I can connect from Netbeans IDE using SYSDBA masterkey.
I can connect from FlameRobin (database admin. tool) using  SYSDBA with other password.
I can not connect from Wild-Fly server using SYSDBA with that other password.

I am really wondering.!!

Comment: Maybe Flamerobin connection is done through an embedded server which doesnt check passwords at all.

Comment: okay, why flameRobin rejects connection with  "masterkey"?

Comment: What value has SecurityDatabase parameter in firebird.conf?

Comment: Can I assume you are using Jaybird 2.2.x?

Comment: yes, I am using jaybird 2.2.10

Answer (score 8):

I assume you are using Jaybird 2.2.x (or earlier) when connecting from Netbeans and Wildfly. With Firebird 3 a new authentication model was introduced called SRP (Secure Remote Password). Jaybird 2.2.x doesn't support this new authentication model (support will be added in Jaybird 3.0), so you need to use the Legacy_Auth plugin.

Users have a separate identity per plugin, this means that you (can) have two users with the name SYSDBA, one for SRP and one for Legacy_Auth. These users have their own passwords.

So when you connect from Netbeans and Wildfly, you need to specify the password of the legacy authentication user. This password appears to be `masterkey`, or actually: `masterke` as legacy passwords are only 8 characters.

When you connect from flamerobin, you can use the 'other' password (of the SRP sysdba user) as flamerobin uses the Firebird 3 `fbclient.dll`/`libfbclient.so` and therefor supports the new SRP authentication model.

As far as I know flamerobin should also be able to authenticate with the password of the legacy sysdba user (when login fails, it should try the next plugin). I will test that tomorrow.

Comment: @kamel2005 I suspect the 'problem' with flamerobin might be due to the order of plugins. You have set `AuthServer` to try Legacy_Auth first, while the (default) for `AuthClient` is to try Srp first. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: is  it important to set the same order both for client and server?

Comment: @kamel2005 I commented earlier that it doesn't depend on order, but it does; I'm not exactly sure which combination allows or disallows it. It seems a bit fishy.

Comment: @kamel2005 It seems to be a combination of order that plugins are tried, and that the first plugin for which the username is known will reject and end the authentication if the password is wrong. I still think it is a bug, and I have asked the Firebird core developers for clarification.