# Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server

Tags: c#, exception, encryption, connection, firebird

i had the same problem like written here:

[Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server with Firebird ado.net provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492890/c-sharp-firebird-3-srp-authentication-model)

I changed to WireCrypt = Enabled (also tryed Disabled), but now i always get the following exception: "Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server".

Here is the function that crashes:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String filename = dialog.FileName;
            String connectionString = @"Server=localhost;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database="+filename+";ServerType=0";
            MessageBox.Show(connectionString);
            FbConnection c = new FbConnection(connectionString);
            c.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter("select * from Users where id = @id", c);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", 7);

            da.Fill(dt);

            MessageBox.Show("RowCount: " + dt.Rows.Count);
        }
```

The place where it crashes, is the c.Open();
I know that i shouldn´t do it that way, otherwise if i leave this line out, it will crash at the fill , which does an automatic open.

Can anybody tell me if there is an additional setting/change needed please.

Comment: Which version of the Firebird .net provider are you using? Also: did you restart the firebird server after changing the `WireCrypt` setting?