# Migrate Firebird 2.5 to 4.0 using ADO.Net provider

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird, firebird-.net-provider, firebird-4.0

I just upgraded my DB to Firebird 4.0 and all seems to work when connecting to the DB using a database management tool.

So now I try to connect, after making sure I've upgarded my ADO.Net to FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient v8.0.1 (latest).

Here is how I create my connection string (yes, db path exists and I made sure that users have modification rights):

```
 FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
 cs.Database = @"C:/myPath/MyDB.FDB";
 cs.DataSource = "localhost";
 cs.UserID = "sysdba";
 cs.Password = "masterkey";
 cs.Dialect = 3;
 cs.Pooling = false;
 cs.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
 // --- Omitted at first - any of the 3 types leads to errors!
 //cs.WireCrypt = FbWireCrypt.Disabled;
 var DBConn = new FbConnection(cs.ConnectionString);
 DBConn.Open();
```

Now, notice I left out `WireCrypt` option (on purpose to start with). My error is:

> Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details

`firebird.log` says:

> Authentication error No matching plugins on server

So I googled around and [found hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571054/workaround-for-incompatible-wire-encryption-levels-in-firebird-ado-net-provider) it may come from wire encryption. Well ok, so I did try all 3 versions of wire encryption - if I use `Required` or `Enabled`, I get the above error. If I use the `Disabled` , I get

> Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server

Furthermore, I tried setting `WireCrypt = Disabled` in `firebird.conf` and in my code, restarted the service and tested again - now I have the same result as with the first two cases:

> Authentication error No matching plugins on server

So I guess I'm missing something here about the encryption plugins - but I couldn't find any valuable information there, thanks for helping out!

UPDATE: here are the settings I tried and the error I got:

**Attempt 1:** all `firebird.conf` defaults (I posted it [here](https://eswys.ch/tmp/firebird.conf) to keep things short here):

Connection string 1:

```
character set=NONE;data source=localhost;initial catalog=C:\Users\DBAccess\MYDB.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;wire crypt=Disabled
```

> Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server

Connection string 2 (wire crypt=Enabled or Required)

> Authentication error No matching plugins on server

**Attempt 2:**

```
WireCrypt = Disabled
```

Connection string 1:

```
character set=NONE;data source=localhost;initial catalog=C:\Users\DBAccess\MYDB.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;wire crypt=Disabled
```

> Authentication error No matching plugins on server

Connection string 2 (wire crypt=Enabled) => same error!

**Attempt 3:**

```
AuthClient = Srp256, Srp
UserManager = Srp
```

Connection string 1:

```
character set=NONE;data source=localhost;initial catalog=C:\Users\DBAccess\MYDB.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;wire crypt=Disabled
```

> Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server

Connection string 2 (wire crypt=Enabled or Required)

> Authentication error No matching plugins on server

**Attempt 4:**

```
AuthClient = Srp256, Srp
UserManager = Srp
WireCryptPlugin = ChaCha, Arc4
WireCrypt = Enabled
ServerMode = Super
```

Connection string (same result with any wire crypt option in the connection string):

```
character set=NONE;data source=localhost;initial catalog=C:\Users\DBAccess\MYDB.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;wire crypt=Enabled
```

> Authentication error No matching plugins on server

NOTE: I also see the following message in `firebird.log`, which is possibly due to the service restart...

> inet_error: read errno = 10054, client host = DESKTOP-1234, address = 127.0.0.1/60348, user = myusername

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I eventually got it to work using following settings:

`firbird.conf`:

```
AuthServer =  Srp256,Srp
UserManager = Srp
WireCrypt = Enabled
```

And connection string code:

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder bld = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
bld.Charset = "NONE";
bld.DataSource = "localhost";
bld.Database = @"C:\Users\DBAccess\MYDB.FDB";
bld.UserID = "SYSDBA";
bld.Password = "masterkey";
bld.WireCrypt = FbWireCrypt.Enabled;
string connStr = bld.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: There is no need to change `AuthClient` for your case. Also be aware that by removing Srp256 from the `AuthServer` list, you're reducing security for clients that do support Srp256. It is better to set it to `AuthServer = Srp256,Srp`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel a quick one: I'm trying the "embedded" version and run into `Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.` - should I open a new thread?

Comment: Yes, definitely, likely you're not actually using Embedded, but just an fbclient.dll without plugins/engine13.dll and other supporting files needed for Firebird Embedded.

Comment: Ok got it working. I think that I copied the old `firebird.conf` file - so all fine there!

Answer (score 4):

The Firebird ADO.net provider version 8 only supports the `Srp` authentication plugin when connecting to Firebird 3.0 or higher, but Firebird 4.0 by default only uses the more secure `Srp256` plugin. You will need to change the `AuthServer` setting in `firebird.conf` to `Srp256,Srp` for the Firebird ADO.net provider to be able to connect.

See also this issue: [Support for Srp256 [DNET942] #864](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/NETProvider/issues/864)

Comment: thanks for the clarification but nothing helps - still the same `No matching plugins on server` error although I tried to play aroung with `firbird.conf` settings. Is there an example setup file known to work? Maybe I did miss installing some plugins (in which case, how  do I know which one?)

Comment: @neggenbe I'll need to try things out, but I won't have time until later this week, maybe you also need to restrict the wire crypt plugin setting to Arc4 only

Comment: Ok just for the record: I remvoved the Firebird 4.0 and replaced it with Firebird 3.0, then restored my database (gback from 2.5) and used the exact same code (even with using `FbWireCrypt.Enabled` and it works seamlessly. So there is something about FB 4.0 that I am missing (I guess this has to do with either the security database or `firebird.conf` in that case)!

Comment: @neggenbe I tested it, and with a default firebird.conf, the only thing I had to modify was using `AuthServer = Srp256,Srp` instead of the default. Make sure your user actually exists for `Srp` user manager (e.g. by connecting to database employee and executing `create user sysdba password 'masterkey' using plugin srp`.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I'll try your config and let you know. But I am not really sure what you mean by "database employee". That sounds `Srp` specific, which I read would be deprecated anyway... Any comment on that?

Comment: @neggenbe `employee` is the example database included with Firebird, and listed in `databases.conf` with the alias `employee`. It is easy to use if you need to connect to any database (e.g. to create a user). As to Srp, there are two parts, the Srp user manager and the Srp family of authentication plugins (which includes Srp, Srp224, Srp256, Srp384 and Srp512), all those authentication plugin use the same user manager, what differs is the hash algorithm they use for their 'user-proof'. Given the Srp auth plugin uses SHA-1, it was decided that using Srp256 (SHA-256) was the better default.

Comment: Ok so basically, if I get you right, the "breaking change" is I need to create users in the TARGET database now, not only in the `security4.fdb`  database, correct? But I read that in the embedded mode, there is no user required... And does Srp require any additional installation (and no, Office is still not the point here :p )

Comment: PS: I tried to add user with ISQL tool and it says user already exists in security database (I think SYSDBA is added by installer). And this whether I connect to the security DB or the target DB. Enabling with your settings gives the same `no plugin` error. Maybe I need to register the path to DLLs in `Firebird_4_0\plugins`? Or anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide all custom settings in the firebird.conf (by default all settings in firebird.conf are commented out, which means they apply the default setting). And no, by default Firebird 3.0 and 4.0 still create users in the security4.fdb, but you need to connect to **any** database to create the user. If you already have the necessary user **for the Srp usermanager**, and `AuthServer` includes Srp then you should be good. And no, Srp does not require additional installation.

Comment: Ok I'll edit with the different settings I used. As for Srp : I installed it locally on my desktop computer (Win10 Pro, not Windows Server) - maybe this is the reason?

Comment: ok, so let me some time to update all settings I tried. Note I only installed Fb 4.0 (x64) with installer, all the rest is default!

Comment: The installer can modify certain settings depending on the options you chose during install. In other words, it may not be 100% default.

Comment: Ok, I think that thanks to this post (https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-compat-legacyauth.html) I found the problem:  I was registering only `AuthClient=srp`, but I also needed to set `AuthServer=spr`

Comment: I have said from the beginning that you need to modify `AuthServer`. Modifying `AuthClient` has no effect for you, because that only influences fbclient.dll usages, and you're not using fbclient.dll. Also, it is best to leave `AuthClient` at its default settings.

Comment: my bad really, didn't get the difference. Thanks for your patience, I owe you a beer :)

Comment: Maybe at a future Firebird conference ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth
on firebird.conf

Comment: Are you able to expand on why this solution works, or perhaps a link to some documentation to support further investigation into this solution?

Comment: Kindly add more details to your answer, explanations on how your code works and how this address the OP's question would be a great help not just for the asker but also for the future researchers.

Comment: ofcourse. fire3, 4 use plugin for authentication, if u alter firebird.conf for use legacy system, firebird will conect with old auth(sysdba, masterkey). https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-compat-legacyauth.html