# Where is the Firebird DB log file located in Windows?

Tags: windows, firebird, logfile, firebird-3.0

I just installed Firebird 3.0.6. When running this command in isql from the documentation:

```
SQL> connect localhost:employee user sysdba password somepassword;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08006
Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details
SQL>
```

When I looked in the C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0 folder. It is not there.

Where should I look for it?

Comment: You can use tools like SysInternals Process Monitor to check all the files Firebird server exe is writing to, thus seeing where it does or tries to write log data

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946309/firebirdsql-error-occurred-during-login-please-check-server-firebird-log-for-de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled Firebird DB as an application in C:\Firebird and everything works. Must have been the permissions issue that is all over the internet.

Comment: If that solved the problem, it would indicate that the user running the Firebird service did not have write access to the `C:\Program Files\ Firebird\Firebird_3_0` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run the Firebird server in application mode, run it as administrator.

This doesn't directly answer your question, the log file still doesn't appear in the installation folder, I don't know why. However, the error will be gone and there is no need for your question anymore :)

Comment: Maybe this helps someone - I found the logfile in this path: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_3_0

Comment: helped me. I encountered an error while trying to connect and received a message to check the logs, that i never found. The connection errors ceased after I ran it as an administrator.